# Android Scale Animation - Reverse Issue

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mobile, android-animation

I managed to add a scale animation to my Image which makes it grow from it original size to a bigger size. However I need to add another copy of the animation code that makes it scale back to its' original size. I am trying to **loop the animation while the boolean is true.**

I played around the parameters a bit but I couldn't make it work. Here's my code so far:

```
class AnimateButton extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Boolean isGlowing = true; //Make it run forever
            while (isGlowing) {
                scal_grow = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1.2f, 0, 1.2f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5);
                scal_grow.setDuration(1500);
                scal_grow.setFillAfter(true);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn_layer.setAnimation(scal_grow);
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (Exception e) { }

                     //Add a reverse animation such that it goes back to the original size

            }
        return null;
     }
}
```

What changes should I make guys?

Comment: Are you creating an AsyncTask to animate a button ?

Comment: Yes I am. To make sure it runs in the background @RamiJemli

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In android, no animation and no UI update can happen on any other thread except the UIThread (the main thread).
Remove the AsyncTask and try using ViewPropertyAnimator which is better than ScaleAnimation in matter of performance. Plus, it's just one line.

To scale :

```
btn_layer.animate().scaleX(1.2f).scaleY(1.2f).setDuration(1500).start();
```

to unscale :

```
btn_layer.animate().scaleX(0.8f).scaleY(0.8f).setDuration(1500).start();
```

**UPDATE**

```
PropertyValuesHolder scalex = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1.2f);
PropertyValuesHolder scaley = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1.2f);
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(btn_layer, scalex, scaley);
anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
anim.setDuration(1500);
anim.start();
```

Comment: I used these two lines one after the other, I don't see the button change though

Comment: You're sure? I'm 100% sure they work. The first one is to scale and the second is to unscale.

Comment: You would probably want to wait before the unscaling, don't do it simultaneously

Comment: When do you want to unscale the button exactly?

Comment: Just a smooth animation of Scaling and Unscaling in a total time span of about 1.5 seconds

Comment: DAYUM! Works like a charm man! Thanks to you and @rharter and Udi Idan :)

Comment: How's the performance of this solution? Any issues on older devices?

Comment: Yes mate. No problems in those?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96391/discussion-between-rami-jemli-and-earthling).

Comment: Repeat  will automatically unscale it, so you don't need to ever do that. You should likely never be using `Thread.sleep()` on Android until you're quite advanced.  What you need to worry about is simply stopping the animation.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend not using the legacy `android.view.animation` animations and use [Property Animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) instead.  The old view animations aren't great, and don't work on the view like you'd expect.

Using property animations, this pulsing animation is quite simple.  You can define it in XML like this:

```
<animator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="1.2"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
```

When you apply this, the animation will repeat indefinitely by reversing.

In Java it would look like this:

```
    PropertyValuesHolder scalex = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1.2f);
    PropertyValuesHolder scaley = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1.2f);
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(btn_layer, scalex, scaley);
    anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    anim.setDuration(1500);
    anim.start();
```

This will give you a much more expected experience, and takes care of the threading and timing for you.  When you want to stop the animation, you simply call `s.cancel()` and you're done.

Comment: This does the animation but it shrinks and scales to the right side. Basically not the animation I had in mind mate. I will however try playing around it a bit

Comment: What is the gravity set on the view?  If it is GRAVITY_RIGHT or GRAVITY_END, or you have it in layout aligned to the right that will happen, as this is actually changing the property of the view, where view animations are only changing what is drawn (i.e. touch targets will be off)

Comment: @rharter This can be achieved using one ObjectAnimator.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @RamiJemli, I am using ObjectAnimator in my example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant one instance of ObjectAnimtor. There is no need for two and an AnimatorSet.

Comment: @rharter I updated your answer, it's simpler using PropertyValuesHolder.

Comment: This also gave me this error and crashed:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: animator

Comment: The Java code gives me this error: "Cannot Resolve method setRepeatMode(int)"

Answer (score 0):

To unscale you can use this:

```
 ScaleAnimation unscal_grow = new ScaleAnimation(1.2f, 1.0f, 1.2f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5);
 unscal_grow .setDuration(1500);
 unscal_grow .setFillAfter(true);
```

A method to scale and unscale:

```
 private void scaleAndUnscale() {
    ScaleAnimation scal_grow = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1.2f, 0, 1.2f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5);
    scal_grow.setDuration(1500);
    scal_grow.setFillAfter(true);

    image1.startAnimation(scal_grow);

    scal_grow.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            ScaleAnimation unscal_grow = new ScaleAnimation(1.2f, 1.0f, 1.2f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5);
            unscal_grow.setDuration(1500);
            unscal_grow.setStartOffset(1500);
            unscal_grow.setFillAfter(true);

            image1.startAnimation(unscal_grow);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to unscale it mate

Comment: I checked it and it works. Regarding Sleep, I don't think your solution for the animation with AsyncTask is is good. You probably want to use a Handler with postDelayed, so it will run on the UI thread and with no need for sleep.

Comment: Actually a simpler solution, if it's suppose to run once, is just make the unscale animation run in onAnimationEnd

Comment: I want it to run while the boolean is true. I've stated that mate :) Can I have the full solution you tried? I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: I've added a method to achieve the scale unscale

Comment: This might work, but the view animation framework you are tying to use is legacy, you should really be using property animations.

Comment: It will work. I do agree that property animations are a better solution, if he targets Android 3.0 or higher.

Comment: If targeting <3.0, use ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.  View Animations are problematic since they don't change actual properties of the view, but just where it is drawn, so touch targets will be off, and other layouts get affected in unexpected ways.

Comment: Altough I do agree that property animations are a better solution, View animations work pretty good, when you are a ware of their limitaions and behaviour. It's usually unexpected, when you don't know what to expect ;)

Comment: @UdiIdan That is VERY reassuring :P